# Why is my vim zero width positive lookbehind storing a backreference?

Tags: vim, backreference, regex-lookarounds

I am using Vim, and I have the following code:

```
print "Number 1 = $no1\n";
print "Number 2 = $no2\n";
```

When I apply the following substitute command

```
$s/.*\(\d\\n\)\@<=\(";\)/\1
```

the result is

```
1\n
2\n
```

and when I substitute with backreference \2 instead

```
$s/.*\(\d\\n\)\@<=\(";\)/\2
```

the result is

```
";
";
```

I thought that I only have one backreference in the regex (the ";) What was stored in \1 appears to be the regex I used within my zero-width positive lookbehind, which I thought would NOT be stored in a backreference.

Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `\(` is always a capturing back reference. From what I can see from a few attempts, what you want is a `\%(`, which is a non-capturing back reference.

So basically, rewriting your substitute as:

```
$s/.*\%(\d\\n\)\@<=\(";\)/\1
```

will put

```
";
```

to backreference `\1`, rather than `\2`

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that there was a non-capturing back reference; that's just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the following substitute command:

```
:%s/.*\(\d\\n\)\@<=\(";\)/\1
```

... the result is:

```
1\n
2\n
```

As should be expected, because you've captured the below expression in the `\1` capturing group:

```
\(\d\\n\)
```

... and when you substitute with backreference `\2` instead

```
:%s/.*\(\d\\n\)\@<=\(";\)/\2
```

... the result is:

```
";
";
```

As should be expected, because you've captured the below expression in the second capturing group:

```
\(";\)
```

I'm unclear what you're trying to do.  What output were you expecting from the above substitutions?

Comment: I think what he wants is look behind without increasing backreference cost.

Comment: Thanks :) That said, I don't understand either what he tries to achieve with the substitution, but that's kinda irrelevant to his question :)

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that using a lookaround with a \(\) group would not increase the backreference count; this clears things up! And as to what I was trying to achieve is beside the point, I just couldn't understand what was going on with the backreferences.